# Android loading large data to horizontal view

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

This is not a question on how to load the data. I have already loaded the data and it works fine. The issue that I am trying to solve is when ever i go to that page / view it seems to show a black screen before showing the data on the screen. which I can solve by putting a spinner on the screen. But my question is how does app like gmail loads all its information on the listview so quickly. I tried using the CursorAdapters but it still takes few second before the screen is populated with the data. The screen only has images and text. at most it loads like 20 data in the list. Can some one please help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is a screen shot of what is displayed on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you are loading heavy data(images not just raw strings). I know its not answer you wanted but im not sure what could you do. Putting it on some background service might help. Again not sure about solution.

Comment: I tried turning of loading the images and its still taking quite a long time to load the values on to the screen

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure than. Have to try it my self tbh. But as far as i can remember i never had issues.